# TinyMCE not being added to element on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tinymce

I'm having some issues applying TinyMCE onto the textarea element.
I have a page with a list of passengers. When you click a passsenger, AJAX is called and it displays info for the passenger, one field which happens to be a textarea element. My problem is that the first passenger (any passenger) you click on loads TinyMCE, but from here on out, it's just a normal textarea with no TinyMCE applied. I don't know what's happening. Here is the following code I have:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(e) {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold, italic, underline, | ,bullist, numlist, | ,outdent, indent, | ,link, unlink, |, code",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
    });

j$('.names strong').click(function(e) {
    //Find passenger ID
    var customer_ID = j$(this).closest('.passenger_Container').find("input[name='customer_ID']").val();
    //Find placement of returned data
    var insert_Data = j$(this).closest('.passenger_Container').find('.package');

    j$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "/include/passenger_Detail.php",
       data: { customer_ID_Data : customer_ID },
       success: function(data) {
            //get returned data and add into appropriate place
            insert_Data.html(data);

            var oldEditor = tinyMCE.get('notes');
            if (oldEditor != undefined) {
                 tinymce.remove(oldEditor);
            }
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'notes');
            //re-initialise WYSIWYG editor. Notes is the ID to re-initialize 
            /*tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'notes');
            tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'notes');*/
       }
    }); 
    });
});

<!-- content is displayed using PHP while loop -->
<div class="passenger_Container bottom-buffer">
    <div class="names row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">
        <!-- Display checkbox -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3"> 
            <strong><?php echo $row['f_Name'].' '.$row['l_Name']; ?></strong> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 hidden-xs"> 
        <!-- display child names -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <!-- Display order status -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2"> 
        <!-- Display form -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="package custom-well well-sm top-buffer">
        <!-- passenger detail goes here. You will find the code in  includes/passenger_Detail.php -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end PHP while loop -->
```

I have left the examples I have tried to get TinyMCE to work. I have a sneaky suspicion bad coding practice is the culprit. Each of the textareas have an ID of #notes which I think is the cause. But looking at documentation I don't think tinyMCE lets you use classes to target textareas. Unless I have to loop through all textareas. I'm just spitballing here.

Please inform me if more info is required. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue but using a unique ID for each of the textarea elements. So instead of each textarea having the ID "notes", it is now "notes_unique customer_ID".

Following is my answer:

```
j$.ajax({        
      type: "POST",
      url: "/include/passenger_Detail.php",
      data: { customer_ID_Data : customer_ID },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log("Returned data: "+data);  
        //get returned data and add into appropriate place
        insert_Data.html(data);
        notes = insert_Data.find('textarea').attr('id');
        var oldEditor = tinyMCE.get('notes_'+customer_ID);
        if (oldEditor != undefined) {
             tinymce.remove(oldEditor);
        }
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'notes_'+customer_ID);
    }
});
```